# Simple C++ connection to mysql database

Tags: c++, mysql

I just started with c++, after reading some tutorials I'm trying to create a simple myqsl connection with a database. Keep in mind that I'm mainly a web developer hence this is a new thing for me. My current code (taken from a tutorial) is this:

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct connection_details
{
    char *server;
    char *user;
    char *password;
    char *database;
};

MYSQL* mysql_connection_setup(struct connection_details mysql_details) {

    MYSQL *connection = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (!mysql_real_connect(connection,mysql_details.server, mysql_details.user, mysql_details.password, mysql_details.database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
      printf("Conection error : %s\n", mysql_error(connection));
      exit(1);
    }

    return connection;
}

MYSQL_RES* mysql_perform_query(MYSQL *connection, char *sql_query) {

   if (mysql_query(connection, sql_query)) {
      printf("MySQL query error : %s\n", mysql_error(connection));
      exit(1);
   }

   return mysql_use_result(connection);
}

int main() {

  MYSQL *conn;      // the connection
  MYSQL_RES *res;   // the results
  MYSQL_ROW row;    // the results row (line by line)

  struct connection_details mysqlD;

  mysqlD.server = "localhost";  // line 46
  mysqlD.user = "root";         // line 47
  mysqlD.password = "root";     // line 48
  mysqlD.database = "backseat"; // line 49

  conn = mysql_connection_setup(mysqlD);

  res = mysql_perform_query(conn, "show tables"); // line 53

  printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");

  while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) !=NULL)
      printf("%s\n", row[0]);


  mysql_free_result(res);
  mysql_close(conn);

  return 0;
}
```

however g++ gives me the followign warning:

```
main.cpp:46:19: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
main.cpp:47:17: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
main.cpp:48:21: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
main.cpp:49:21: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
main.cpp:53:48: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
```

Which is beyond my understanding at the time being, although the program works.
What I did in order to remove the warning was the following:

```
char s[] = "localhost";
char u[] = "root";
char p[] = "root";
char d[] = "backseat";
```

and then

```
mysqlD.server = s;
mysqlD.user = u;
mysqlD.password = p;
mysqlD.database = d;
```

That took care of the warning but I assume there must be a better way & explanation on how I should take care of this.
Moreover I tried to use:

```
struct connection_details
{
    string *server;
    string *user;
    string *password;
    string *database;
};
```

But that didn't take care the warning on line 53 plus all hell broke loose after doing this.
My question is how should I be approaching simple mysql connection, why did those warnings came up and was it a bad idea to use strings in the struct?

I'm sorry for the long post, but I'm on a learning curve here and there a lot of things to take in.

PS: Any good tutorials / guides will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some basics. I don't know about good tutorials to link to, but I'll explain what you're doing wrong:

First of all, when you're writing C++, you should use `string` rather than `char*`. You should read up the details of `char*`; it's a pointer and handling it is therefore significantly different from handling a `string`.

What happens in your code is that you assign *the address of a* string literal like `"localhost"` to a `char*` (because it's a pointer). The problem is, gcc converts string literals to constants, which are read-only (as the warning tells you). The type `char*` however implies that the contents of the string can be changed. Change the type to `const char*` to get rid of the warning.

Here's some code to illustrate the issue:

```cpp
char* a;
const char* b;

a = "foo";
b = "bar";

a[0] = 'a'; // you're changing the constant string!
b[0] = 'b'; // compiler error; b is const

a = "foz"; // both allowed because you're not changing
b = "baz"; // the string, but only the pointer
```

The easier option is to use `string`:

```cpp
struct connection_details
{
    string server;
    string user;
    string password;
    string database;
}
```

You shouldn't use pointers here. `string` manages the low-level memory stuff internally. Now the problem is that you're using the C-level MySQL binding, which expects `char*` rather than `string`. To call it when you're using `string`s in your code, use `c_str()` for conversion:

```cpp
connection.server.c_str()
```

and so on.

Alternatively, you might want to use a higher-level C++ API to connect to MySQL. If you're learning C++, you'll be better off avoiding C APIs if possible. There is, for example, [MySQL++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/), but I don't know it and therefore cannot recommend it. A higher-level API is provided by [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net), which works with multiple database backends (including MySQL).